# wordpress add new thumbnail size of image

Tags: wordpress, image, image-size

wordpress admin has 3 default image sizes i.e thumbnail,medium,large.How can i add one more type (ex:700px X 500px)so that if i upload an image it also saves in all four sizes.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should select an answer as correct. Also, you can upvote answers which were helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your functions.php file.

```
add_image_size( 'name-of-size', 700, 500, true );
```

More information can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Add_New_Post_Thumbnail_Sizes).

**Also note that you will need to regenerate thumbnails for those images which were previously uploaded, if you need them in the new size.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_image_size( 'new-thumb', 110,100,true);
```

syntax ==> `<?php add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop ); ?>`

Refer Here [**Add Image Size**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)